# Pandas drop function not working in a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas

all!
I am pretty confused by this and for the life of me cannot figure out the error.
I am trying to go through all the strings in a data frame and remove the ones that do not contain the string 'Barry Bonds'.

So far I have managed to be able to drop rows by their index:

```
bb_db.drop(bb_db.index[1])
```

This is successful at dropping the row at that index, however when I throw it into this for loop:

```
for i in range(len(bb_db)):
    if 'Barry Bonds' in bb_db['player_names'][i]:
        bb_db.drop(bb_db.index[i])
        print (i)
```

I get the entire dataframe, even though the i variable prints out a ton of indexes with the if statement as being true.

Thank you!

Comment: `drop` doesn't mutate your current DataFrame unless you ask it to, with `inplace=True`.

Comment: Doing that, i get a key error at the first index.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`drop` doesn't mutate your current DataFrame unless you ask it to, with `inplace=True`.

With that being said, a for loop is almost certainly not the easiest approach here. Why not just boolean indexing with the `str` accessor on your column, i.e. with [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

```
bb_db[~bb_db.player_names.str.contains('Barry Bonds')]
```

Comment: Okay I will for sure try that! What does the ~ do?

Comment: The tilde is negating my boolean Series. Think of it like `not`.

Comment: @TomSlesinger You're welcome. Some further reading would be [Boolean Indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) in the docs. Also, not a big deal but usually people avoid inappropriate language on SO to try and maintain some level of professionalism :)

Comment: Haha I changed it, thank you so much again was stuck on this simple problem for so long :D

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
for i in range(len(bb_db)):
    if 'Barry Bonds' in bb_db['player_names'][i]:
        bb_db = bb_db.drop(bb_db.index[i])
        # or this works too..
        # bb_db.drop(bb_db.index[i], inplace=True)
        print (i)
```