# Dropping rows in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem that I have been dealing with 2 days now, and even though I read the documentation and answers to similar questions on StackOverflow, I cannot come with a solution.

I have a dataset with pairs of questions, witch I should label with duplicate or not. On the training dataset, I implemented cleaning and vectorization - word2vec. Unfortunately, for some rows word2vec returns emply value (nan), as they don't have any words after cleaning.

So, I'm trying to drop this lines, but it simply do not work.

```
LEN = len(train1)
print("Innitial lenght: ")
print(len(train1))
print("Empty rows: ")
for i in range(0, LEN): 
    if ((type(train1['q1_vec'][i]) != np.ndarray) or (type(train1['q2_vec'][i])!= np.ndarray)): 
        print(i)
        train1.drop(train1.index[i])
print("Lenght after cleaning")
print(len(train1))
```

I got the results:

```
Innitial lenght: 
  258528
Empty rows: 
  29296
  59523
  80284
  ...
  219103
Lenght after cleaning
  258528
```

Which means I have not drop anything and I cannot apply any function of distance, such as `scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean` etc.

I tried with Lambda function, but also did not succeed.

```
train1['euclidean'] = train1.apply(lambda row: dist.euclidean(row['q1_vec'], row['q2_vec']) if ((type(row['q1_vec']) == np.ndarray) or (type(row['q2_vec']) == np.ndarray)) else None, axis=1)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried to use `train1.drop(train1.index[i], inplace=True)`? Pandas creates copies of DataFrames if you don't signal the operation should be inplace.

Comment: If that is the case, this could be marked as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43667979/pandas-drop-function-not-working-in-a-for-loop). Both answers there would solve the problem.

Comment: It messes up the  indexes when in a loop. It gives errors as "KeyError: 29296L" after it deletes a row.

Comment: Ok. Can you post the output of `print(train1[['q1_vec', 'q2_vec']])`? Now that I take a closer look, the fact you're testing the type of each row seems wrong (every row in pandas should be of same data type).

Answer (score 0):

Using a parameter `inplace=true` will help in dropping the records inline. For example:

```
df.drop(df.index[i], inplace=True)
```