# pandas conditional drop rows in for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

My Pandas DataFrame has 17543 rows. I want to drop a row, only if every column contains 'nan'. I tried instructions as per the link [drop rows in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43667979/pandas-drop-function-not-working-in-a-for-loop)
but did not help. The following is my code

```
NullRows=0
for i in range(len(SetMerge.index)):
    if(SetMerge.iloc[i].isnull().all()):
        df=SetMerge.drop(SetMerge.index[i])
        NullRows +=1

print("total null rows : ", NullRows)
```

I get only one row dropped in df with 17542 rows whereas NullRows output is 30.

Comment: Why don't use dataframe.dropna(how='all') ?

Comment: In other words, you should not be using a loop at all

Comment: Improved readability

Comment: Anna is on point here, don't use a for loop for this.

Answer (score 0):

`drop` doesn't mutate your `SetMerge`. Thus, you need to re-assign `SetMerge` after `drop`, or use another function.
It is written in answer, by link which you've posted here and checked. Specify inplace=True option for mutation.